# Gracefully shut down a TCP socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock, irc

I'm writing an IRC client in C++ and currently I'm having an issue where, upon exit, I do:

```
Send("QUIT :Quit\r\n"); // just an inline, variadic send() wrapper
shutdown(m_hSocket, SD_BOTH);
closesocket(m_hSocket);

WSAShutdown();
```

However, the issue is that the QUIT message is not being sent. I've sniffed the packets coming from the client and infact this message is never sent. I believe this is an issue with the socket not being flushed, but I have no idea how to do this and Google suggested disabling Nagle's algorithm but I doubt this is good practice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For when you do get this working, remember that some IRC networks will not show a custom quit message until you have been signed in for > 5 minutes (the actual length varies depending on network). It's not an answer to your current problem, but it's a gotcha that can be confusing later on :)

Comment: Interesting point, but I've had it up for a couple of ours now, quit, and still got:
Read error: Connection reset by peer

Comment: yup, I just thought I'd mention it for when you get the socket issue fixed :)

Comment: There is no flush operation on sockets. Small data is  collected for about 40ms and then send. Its called Naggle algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should check the return value of `send`: are the data you attempt to send actually accepted by the network stack? (In general this should be done after each and every `send` call, not just in this case).

Assuming the data is accepted, then AFAIK it should be actually transmitted as a result of calling `shutdown`. You might try using `SO_LINGER` to see if it makes a difference, see [Graceful Shutdown, Linger Options, and Socket Closure on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738547).

Comment: Even using the fix in the comments of that MSDN article, I still get the error when closing sockets at exit. It seems WSACleanup() causes it. Thanks anyway Jon! :D

Comment: After calling `shutdown()`, you should not call `closesocket()` until after the remote peer has acknowledged the disconnect request, by calling `recv()` in a loop (optionally with `select()` to know when to call `recv()`) until it returns 0 (or an error).