# Flaw in transferring file through tcp

Tags: python, windows, shell, sockets, python-3.x

Server-side code. Opens a file, reads a bit of the file, sends that bit, till it is finished

```
f = open("{}".format(filename), "rb")
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    print("Sending...")
    client.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
print("Finished sending")   
f.close()
client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
client.close()
```

Client-side code, creates the file receives a bit of it, writes it to the file until it is finished.

```
f = open("{}".format(filename), "ab+")
l = client.recv(1024)
while (l):
    print("Receiving...")
    f.write(l)
    l = client.recv(1024)
f.close()
print("Transmission completed")
```

1. I know that I have to use `socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` to notify the reciever that the file has finished, but further sends are disallowed. Is there a way to bypass that? Maybe use another command like `.shutdown()`? I need to keep the connection for further sends/receives.
2. When dealing with complex files, somehow I receive more than I should. I am sure than the client writes irrelevant previous data to the file, received with `client.recv(1024)`. Is there any way to "throw away", or empty the data safely  before the file's data arrive?

.jpg file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjXBZ.png

.txt file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb8j5.png

Comment: maybe it's because of option "ab+". "а" is for appending, not for creating new clear file and write to it as "w"

Comment: Speaking Code is right. You should use `'wb'` (w for write, b for binary mode).

Comment: It is nice to use `shutdown`. But for a true [graceful shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27777498/3545273) , the server program should try to read from the socket until the client (receiver part) has closed the connection.

Comment: You don't have to shutdown...Send the size of the file first, then the file.  Read exactly the number of bytes indicated by the size.  Then you can send another file.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840341/235698) has an example.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two intentions behind the question. First, learning the things; second, implementing something that is cool and that works (usefull). Part of the learning process is getting the passive knowledge via reading the documentation -- this is for [opening the file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), and using the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) construct.

However, part of the learning is also learning *a bigger picture*, and learning how others (more capable) solve the things. This can be done via reading source codes of the existing solution, and trying to understand the code.

I suggest to get the `paramiko` module (https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko.git), and to study `sftp_client.py`, `sftp_server.py`, and the `demos/`.

True, it is much more complex than the few lines that you tried, but you may learn a lot, and the knowledge of how to use paramiko may be valuable for you in future. Also, you will find more questions to focus learning to. ;)