# Sending Encrypted Data Through Socket And Decrypting Doesn't Work

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, encryption, aes

I am creating a simple encryption software. The problem I currently have is that sending encrypted aes file data through a socket doesn't work. At the receiving end, the file that should be written to is empty. I have looked through my code for a good while and can't see to solve it.

I have made a version without networking.
I have been able to send a small file up to 8 KB on a different version

My Program Is Function Based So The Program Branches Off From The Main Menu To Other Menues And Functions. Since There is A Bit Of Jumping, It Would Be Best To Show All The Code.
https://github.com/BaconBombz/Dencryptor/blob/Version-2.0/Dencryptor.py

The socket connects, and all required data is sent. Then, the file is AES encrypted and sent through the socket. The Receiving end writes encrypted data to a file and decrypts it. The program will say the file was sent but on the recieving end, the program spits out a struct error because the file that should have the encrypted data is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is too non-[minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so here's a minimal example of downloading an unencrypted file.  Also, TCP is a streaming protocol and using sleeps to separate your data is incorrect.  Define a protocol for the byte stream instead.  This is the protocol of my example:

1. Open the connection.
2. Send the UTF-8-encoded filename followed by a newline.
3. Send the encoded file size in decimal followed by a newline.
4. Send the file bytes.
5. Close the connection.

Note this is Python 3 code since Python 2 is obsolete and support has ended.

**server.py**

```
from socket import *
import os

CHUNKSIZE = 1_000_000

# Make a directory for the received files.
os.makedirs('Downloads',exist_ok=True)

sock = socket()
sock.bind(('',5000))
sock.listen(1)

with sock:
    while True:
        client,addr = sock.accept()

        # Use a socket.makefile() object to treat the socket as a file.
        # Then, readline() can be used to read the newline-terminated metadata.
        with client, client.makefile('rb') as clientfile:
            filename = clientfile.readline().strip().decode()
            length = int(clientfile.readline())
            print(f'Downloading {filename}:{length}...')
            path = os.path.join('Downloads',filename)

            # Read the data in chunks so it can handle large files.
            with open(path,'wb') as f:
                while length:
                    chunk = min(length,CHUNKSIZE)
                    data = clientfile.read(chunk)
                    if not data: break # socket closed
                    f.write(data)
                    length -= len(data)

            if length != 0:
                print('Invalid download.')
            else:
                print('Done.')
```

**client.py**

```
from socket import *
import os

CHUNKSIZE = 1_000_000

filename = input('File to upload: ')

sock = socket()
sock.connect(('localhost',5000))
with sock,open(filename,'rb') as f:
    sock.sendall(filename.encode() + b'\n')
    sock.sendall(f'{os.path.getsize(filename)}'.encode() + b'\n')

    # Send the file in chunks so large files can be handled.
    while True:
        data = f.read(CHUNKSIZE)
        if not data: break
        sock.sendall(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it and see what happens. Also, I know that python 2.7 will be ending support and most of my other programs are running python 3. The code seems nice but what got me into this was large files. I had tried a listening socket for 64000 bits (8KB) and that worked, but I needed a way to split the file into chunks and send them to be re-assembled.

Comment: @BaconBombz Updated with chunking of files.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It took a while to integrate Diffie-Hellman key exchange but I got it to work. Also, I didn't really intend to use sleeps to organize data transfer. I just tried making the interface a bit nicer because all those lines popping up instantly doesn't look too nice.

Comment: @BaconBombz FYI, if you don't define a protocol like I did and just for example `send(b'abc')` and `send(b'def')` a `recv(100)` could get `b'a'` or `b'ab'` or `b'abcdef'` or anything in between.  It's like reading a file...you need newlines or nulls or byte counts or some method to decide where messages start and end, and buffering until you have a complete message.

Comment: @BaconBombz Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840026/235698) for another example.

Comment: I encountered that problem but remembered that you mentioned to add b'/n'.  Thanks for all the help. I just need to fine tune some stuff. I just have a lot of problems dealing with encoding and byte form. I didn't really learn much and just grew of existing code.

Comment: This will go out of whack for file names which contain literal newlines. A better solution is to send a null byte as the end of file marker, as that is completely disallowed in Unix file names.

Comment: @tripleee it won’t handle bad clients not following protocol either. It is *an example*