# How to ingnore \n in binary until actual new line marker appears

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, utf-8, binary, aes

I have some text that I want to encode. Once it is encoded, it has "\n" in it. I then have python add b'\n' to add a new line. My socket thinks the first \n is the end of the file when it is actually part of the text.

I have looked through my code and this is just something I don't know how to fix.

Generating The Binary Data

```
print("Calculating Key")
sharedKey = str((int(recieverPublicKey) ** int(privateKey)) % int(mod))
sharedKey = hashlib.sha256(sharedKey.encode())
sharedKey = sharedKey.hexdigest()
sharedKey = sharedKey[0:32]
print("Encrypting Key")
initVector = 16 * '\x00'
sharedKey = bytes(str(sharedKey), encoding='utf-8')
encryptor = AES.new(sharedKey, AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
encryptedKey = encryptor.encrypt(dencryptionKey)
print(encryptedKey)
time.sleep(0.1)
print("Sending Encryption Key")
sock.sendall(encryptedKey + b'\n')
```

Decoding

```
sharedKey = str((int(senderPublicKey ** int(privateKey))) % int(mod))
sharedKey = hashlib.sha256(sharedKey.encode())
sharedKey = sharedKey.hexdigest()
sharedKey = sharedKey[0:32]
initVector = 16 * '\x00'
print("Recieving Encryption Key")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("Decrypting Key")
encryptedKey = clientFile.readline()
print(encryptedKey)
encryptedKey = encryptedKey.strip().decode()
print(encryptedKey)
initVector = 16 * '\x00'
sharedKey = bytes(str(sharedKey), encoding='utf-8')
decryptor = AES.new(sharedKey, AES.MODE_CBC, initVector)
encryptedKey = encryptedKey[2:-2]
print(encryptedKey)
for x in range(8):
    encryptedKeyPart = encryptedKey[0:16]
    print(encryptedKey)
    encryptedKey = encryptedKey[16:-1]
    dencryptionKey = dencryptionKey +    decryptor.decrypt(encryptedKeyPart).decode('utf-8')
    print(dencryptionKey)
```

Output on recieving side

```
b';l\xb8\xd7{\xa7Wt\x99\xb6\xc2\xfa\xf8\x8c\xe6\xd7=\x1d\x8e\x0b\r\x8e\xa4\xee\xa3\x84\xca\xfd\x91L\xda\xbb\x82\xc3\x93\x0f\xec\xd9o\xa7V\x1fs\x89{\x87\xd3\xf0\xc3\xba\x8f\xd9\xd0v\x18k-\xd9\xb1C&Y\x82+\xb8\xb6\x85:\xfd\x9f\x13\xea\xd8v\xadG\x11_\xbf4r\xb6\xa3\n'
```

Output on sending side

```
b';l\xb8\xd7{\xa7Wt\x99\xb6\xc2\xfa\xf8\x8c\xe6\xd7=\x1d\x8e\x0b\r\x8e\xa4\xee\xa3\x84\xca\xfd\x91L\xda\xbb\x82\xc3\x93\x0f\xec\xd9o\xa7V\x1fs\x89{\x87\xd3\xf0\xc3\xba\x8f\xd9\xd0v\x18k-\xd9\xb1C&Y\x82+\xb8\xb6\x85:\xfd\x9f\x13\xea\xd8v\xadG\x11_\xbf4r\xb6\xa3\ng\xb0\xde\xa9jW\x8d\x85T\x06mR\x0e\xfe\xcar\xaa\x17\x98j\x92lV\x07\xf2}\xad%\x0c\x01\xe4\xf1\xd7=\x8a\xa7\xeb\xd2\xb2c\xb8\x88\xb0\x9b\n'
```

I wanted it to receive all the data and start decrypting the text. The programs stops at a \n which is supposed to be part of the text and doesn't read the rest causing .decode('utf-8') to throw an error because it is unfinished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data you are sending contains a newline, you can't use a newline as a delimiter to the message.  As in your [other question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840341/235698), send the size of the encryption key and a newline, then the encryption key.  On the receiving side, receive the size of the encryption key terminated by the newline, then read exactly that number of bytes for the key itself.

Comment: Hmm I thought I would have to do something extremely complicated. It took me a good 3 days to try and fix this section of the program but I am getting close.