# Send big file over socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have a video file and want to send it over socket. Video is send to the client but video is not playable and also video size received is 2 KB. And acutely video size is 43 MB.  What is the problem?

**Server:**

```
import socket

try:

    soc = socket.socket()
    print('socked created.')
    host = ''
    port = 8080

    soc.bind((host, port))
    print('soc bound.')

    soc.listen(10)
    print('waiting for connecting...')

    con, addr = soc.accept()
    print('server connected to IP: ' + addr[0] + " port: " + str(addr[1]))

    while True:

        filename = input('enter filename: ')
        file = open(filename, 'rb')
        sendfile = file.read(9000000)
        con.send(sendfile)
        print("file has been send.")
        break

    con.close()
    soc.close()

except socket.error as err:
    print('error ', str(err))
```

**client:**

```
import socket

soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('socked created. waiting for connecting to server...')

server_address = ("192.168.1.3", 8080)

soc.connect(server_address)
print('connected to the server.')

while True:
    recvfile = soc.recv(9000000)
    savefilebyname = input("enter file name: ")
    openfile = open(savefilebyname, 'wb')
    openfile.write(recvfile)
    openfile.close()
    break

print("File has been received.")

soc.close()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the return value of `send` and `recv`.  The `9000000` value is a **maximum** but not guaranteed value to send/recv.  Alternatively, use `sendall`.

For `recv`, you have to loop until you receive all the data.  If you close the socket after the file is sent, `recv` will return zero when all the data is received.

FYI, your `while True:` in both files never loops due to the `break`, so they are unnecessary.

Here's something that should work...

**server.py**

```
import socket

soc = socket.socket()
soc.bind(('',8080))
soc.listen(1)

print('waiting for connection...')
with soc:
    con,addr = soc.accept()
    print('server connected to',addr)
    with con:
        filename = input('enter filename to send: ')
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            sendfile = file.read()
        con.sendall(sendfile)
        print('file sent')
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

soc = socket.socket()
soc.connect(('localhost',8080))
savefilename = input("enter file name to receive: ")
with soc,open(savefilename,'wb') as file:
    while True:
        recvfile = soc.recv(4096)
        if not recvfile: break
        file.write(recvfile)
print("File has been received.")
```

Comment: Also see [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840341/235698) showing another technique to upload files where the filename and size is sent as metadata to the server.