# How to send python socket bytes and strings?

Tags: python, sockets, helper

I want to send images and text for the server from the client file. But since I'm new to the socket, I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

codes:

```
#server.py
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", 1236))
s.listen(5)
c, addr = s.accept()
image_datas, d1, d2 = c.recv(1024)
f = open("C:\\Users\\SD\\Desktop\\image.jpg", "wb")
while image_datas:
    f.write(image_datas)
    image_datas = c.recv(1024)
print(d1,d2)
f.close()
c.close()
s.close()


#client.py
import socket
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect(("tcp.ngrok.io", ))
f = open("image.jpg", "rb")
img_data = f.read()
data1 = "hello"
data2 = "server"
c.send(img_data,data2,data3)
f.close()
c.close()
```

Comment: You really need to start by reading [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html).

Comment: Plenty of similar questions and answers, such as: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56194446/235698

Comment: Please help me. How do I assign incoming data to variables?