# Python socket hangs on connect/accept

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send packets using `sockets`, and was able to do so just fine until this morning. I'm not sure what's going on. The packets are showing up in `tcpdump` but the server and the client cannot connect to each other.

netcat.py

```py
import socket
import argparse
import sys
import os
import re
import threading


def convertContent(content: str = "") -> bytes:
    byteContent = []
    # grab the hex from the content
    for i in range(len(content)):
        if content[i] == "\\" and content[i+1] == "x":
            byteContent.append(f"{content[i+2]}{content[i+3]}")

    # grab the non hex from the content, split it on the hex
    stringContent = re.split(r"\\x.{2}", content)

    byteIndex = 0
    newContent = b""
    # Re add the non-hex content, and the hex content
    for word in stringContent:
        newContent += word.encode()
        if byteIndex < len(byteContent):
            newContent += bytes.fromhex(byteContent[byteIndex])
            byteIndex += 1
    newContent = newContent.replace(b"\\n", b"\n").replace(b"\\r", b"\r")
    return newContent


class Netcat():
    '''
    Netcat class that can be used to send/receive TCP packets
    '''
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def createSocket(cls):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # Address might be in a TIME_WAIT status, ignore this
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # Port might be in a TIME_WAIT status, ignore this
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        return sock

    @classmethod
    def send(cls, hostname: str = "127.0.0.1", srcPort: int = 0, destPort: int = 9999, content: str = "", buffer_size: int = 1024):
        srcPort = int(srcPort)
        destPort = int(destPort)
        try:
            content = convertContent(content=content)
        except:
            pass
        sock = cls.createSocket()

        # Set the source port before sending
        sock.connect((hostname, destPort))
        sock.sendall(content)
        # shutdown might be redundant/unnecessary (tells connected host that we're done sending data)
        sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        while True:
            data = sock.recv(buffer_size)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
        sock.close()

    @classmethod
    def receive(cls, port: int = 9999, buffer_size: int = 1024):
        if port <= 1024 and os.geteuid() != 0:
            print(f"Listening on port {port} requires superuser privileges!")
            return
        host = ""
        sock = cls.createSocket()
        sock.bind((host, port))
        sock.listen(10)
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(buffer_size)
            if not data:
                break
        conn.close()

threading.Thread(target=Netcat.receive,daemon=True).start()
Netcat.send(content="test")
```

*Note*: I am sending the packets from one VM to another, rather than sending to myself, but it would be a lot to ask people to spin up a bunch of VMs to reproduce this. The `hostname` param in the send method *should* be the actual IP of the receiving machine

I've thrown some print statements, and the server stops on `sock.accept()`, while the client hangs on `sock.connect((hostname, destPort))`

I checked the hostname for the server, and it's listening on `(0.0.0.0, 8888)` (assuming 8888 is the port param), which means its listening on all interfaces on that port, so I dont know why its refusing to connect

I tcpdumped on the server, and its getting the packets, it gets a `SYN`, then sends out a `SYN, ACK`, but the rest of the packets are marked as re-transmissions.

I've tried looping the accept & connect lines, thinking maybe some sort of race condition was occurring, but no matter what I do the client can't connect to the server.

Edit: This works on my local machine, but still breaks when I try to send packets over the network. The first 2 steps of the handshake go through `SYN` & `SYN, ACK`, but not the third `ACK`

Comment: You don't bind in a client.  Just connect.  Make sure the port used in `bind` on the server is the port used in `connect` on the client.  That's not clear from your non-reproducible example, but the default ports used don't agree.

Comment: @marktolonen afaik you can bind on the client to control the source port. In the server `port` refers to the same port as `destPort` in client. The default values might not match, but they match when I send them. When I get back to my computer I’ll make that more clear, but how is my example not reproducible?

Comment: Reproducible means the code is self-contained, we can just copy the server and client scripts and run them with no additional code changes and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @marktolonen edited my post. Should be reproducible now

Comment: @Lesshawn Missing imports and code that actually calls the functions.  You mentioned "The default values might not match, but they match when I send them".  That code is missing.  How do you call the functions?  And you *shouldn't* call bind on the client.

Comment: @marktolonen, will post the full file when I get back to my pc, how would one control the source port then without binding?

Comment: Binding is to set the server port.  The client ports are chosen from unused ports during connect/accept.  [Working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194446/send-big-file-over-socket/56194810#56194810)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind in the client.  Working example below, but minor changes to make a standalone script:

```py
import socket
import threading

def receive(port: int = 9999, buffer_size: int = 1024):
    host = ""
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Address might be in a TIME_WAIT status, ignore this
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen()
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(buffer_size)
        if not data:
            break
        print(data)
    conn.close()

def send(hostname: str = "127.0.0.1", destPort: int = 9999, content: str = b"test", buffer_size: int = 1024):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Address might be in a TIME_WAIT status, ignore this
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    # Removed bind
    sock.connect((hostname, destPort))
    sock.sendall(content)
    # shutdown might be redundant/unnecessary (tells connected host that we're done sending data)
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(buffer_size)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
    sock.close()
    
threading.Thread(target=receive,daemon=True).start()
send()
```

Output:

```py
b'test'
```

Comment: Is there no way to choose which port to send from? Sending packets from specific ports to specific ports is required for this

Comment: You have a 1:1 connection between client and server.  Why do you think you need to specify a source port?

Comment: The purpose of this program is to trigger IDS rules, some of which require a source and destination port. In order to trigger the rule I the packer needs the correct source port

Comment: I removed bind, but still can't get the devices to connect. I edited my post to make it as reproducible as possible (see note)

Comment: My issue was completely unrelated to this. The device that was forwarding the packets from the sender to the receiver wasn’t forwarding correctly

Comment: @LeshawnRice So why did you mark this answer as correct? Not that there's anything wrong with it, but it didn't solve your problem. It seems to me that you should just delete this question.