# i am trying to encrypt send the data over with socket receving it and then decrypting it

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming

i am trying to encrypt send the data over with socket receving it and then decrypting it but i get this error ValueError: Incorrect IV length (it must be 16 bytes long)

I tried this i for my client

it takes the encrypted code which is a byte and tries to decrypt it by passing it as a str first and removing the symbols i don't need at then making it a byte again

```
import socket
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

def recv_decrypt(encrypted_code):
encrypted_text, iv = encrypted_code.split(',')\[0\], encrypted_code.split(',')\[1\]
iv = iv\[2:\]
iv = iv.strip("'")
encrypted_text = encrypted_text\[2:\]
encrypted_text = encrypted_text.strip("'")
encrypted_text = bytes(encrypted_text, 'ascii')
iv = bytes(iv, 'ascii')

    my_key = b'D\xb7\x12t\x85.\xb7\xe7\xea\x08\xed\xd4\xf7\xa3\x9a\x80'
    password = "{hi&wJO@sVDVUq$"
    key = PBKDF2(password, my_key, dkLen=32)

    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
    original = unpad(cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text), AES.block_size)
    print(original)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('localhost', 43785))

while True:
msg = client.recv(1024)
recv_decrypt(encrypted_code=msg.decode())
```

And this for my server code

this part encrypts the message from the user and sends it as a byte

```
import socket
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

def send_encrypted(msg, client):
    try:
        my_key = b'D\xb7\x12t\x85.\xb7\xe7\xea\x08\xed\xd4\xf7\xa3\x9a\x80'
        password = "{hi&wJO@sVDVUq$"

        key = PBKDF2(password, my_key, dkLen=32)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
        encrypted_data = cipher.encrypt(pad(bytes(msg), AES.block_size))
        iv_data = cipher.iv

        send_data = f'{encrypted_data},{iv_data}'
        client.send(bytes(send_data.encode()))


    except Exception as e:
        print(f"something went wrong in the encrypt section error code: {e}")
        pass

server_ip = "localhost"
connection_port = 43785

Server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Server.bind((server_ip, connection_port))
Server.listen()
client, address = Server.accept()

while True:
    msg = input("MSG: ")
    send_encrypted(msg=msg.encode('ascii'), client=client)
```

but it keeps giving me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\GChat\cleen.py", line 30, in <module>
    recv_decrypt(encrypted_code=msg.decode())
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\GChat\cleen.py", line 20, in recv_decrypt
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\GChat\venv\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 228, in new
    return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\GChat\venv\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
    return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\GChat\venv\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 287, in _create_cbc_cipher
    raise ValueError("Incorrect IV length (it must be %d bytes long)" %
ValueError: Incorrect IV length (it must be 16 bytes long)
```

i am expecting it to be able to send from one file the encrypted part and from the other script be able to decrypt it

Comment: TCP is not message-based. Do not assume one send equals one recv. It is a byte *stream* and you must check the return value of both send and recv.

Comment: and how would i do that?

Comment: There are indentation problems in the first code snippet. Please repost it with correct indentation.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Unless the socket is non-blocking there's no need to check the return value of `send()` -- it will send it all or raise an exception. You can check the length received with `len(msg)`.

Comment: But you need to design your protocol so you know how big each message will be. One option is to send the length before the message. Then the server reads the length, then calls `Server.recv(expected_length, socket.MSG_WAITALL)` to wait for that number of bytes.

Comment: I have No idea how to do that as Socket is very new to me

Comment: @Barmar Then why does `.sendall` exist?  From the `.send` docs, emphasis mine: " Returns the number of bytes sent. **Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data.**"

Comment: @ClashersLab The data content doesn't matter.  What matters is understanding how TCP works.  There are *many* example since this is a common newbie mistake.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840341/235698) for example but there are many others.

Comment: @ClashersLab Also see the [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#socket-programming-howto).

Comment: @MarkTolonen That documentation doesn't distinguish blocking vs. non-blocking. If you make the socket non-blocking, `send()` will not wait for enough buffer space and returns early.

Comment: @Barmar Try sending (in one send) >2GB.  It doesn't error but it returns less than data sent.  That's talking to localhost on Windows which seems to support huge buffers on localhost.  Between two computers I suspect it will send much less.  The socket HOWTO repeats what I said in the 3rd paragraph of [Using a Socket](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket).

Comment: Guys, POSIX requires that `send()` behaves as stated by @Barmar. You can’t cite Python documentation as a normative reference.