# Socket with if-loops does not give a consistent result

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, qgis

The program is continuously receiving data from the sender side. And I have a checked/unchecked button when I make it checked it runs the `if` part...that's good. Now I make it unchecked then `else` part runs and prints `Unchecked going to close socket`, but `s.shutdown(10)` & `s.close()` not closing the socket it shows the **error s.shutdown(10) is not a socket object OS [Errno 10022] an invalid argument is supplied** Why its not closing the socket or is there other any way to close it.

**Additional Requirement**

if my socket get closed again i want to make it checked (2nd time) to run `if` part again to receive data from sender computer is it possible to start socket again without closing my program.

```
def show_markers(self):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostbyname('192.168.225.12')
    s.connect((host, port))
    scale=0

    while True:

        if self.iconAction.isChecked():
            print ('Checked')
            m = QgsVertexMarker(self.iface.mapCanvas())
            data = s.recv(SIZE)
            data1 = s.recv(SIZE)
            c = data.decode()
            d = data1.decode()
            x = float(c)
            y = float(d)
            print("printing X :", x)
            print("printing Y :", y)
            rect = QgsRectangle(float(x)-scale, float(y)-scale, float(x)+scale, float(y)+scale)
            me = self.iface.mapCanvas()
            me.setExtent(rect)
            me.refresh()
            m.setCenter(QgsPointXY(x, y))
            m.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
            m.setIconSize(7)
            m.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_X)  # or ICON_CROSS, ICON_X
            m.setPenWidth(3)

        else:
            print('Unchecked going to close socket')
            s.shutdown(10)
            s.close()
```

***I am assuming it should work like:***

1. 1st time click on button ---> Checked & if part run [working]
2. 2nd time click on button ---> Unchecked & else part run to close the socket [not closing]
3. 3rd time click on button ---> again it Checked and receive data from sender computer [is it possible]

Comment: See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309811/start-stop-python-plugin-during-execution-by-just-clicking-on-plugin-button) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311588/toggle-unchecked-button-is-not-closing-the-socket-qgis)

Comment: @B.Shefter both questions asked by me only that's not the solution i want.

Comment: @t.m.adam please take a look here

Comment: I guess your socket is closed and you do not reconnect then again.

Comment: @Michael that i asked can i connect or disconnect as many times i want in a program. is there any way to receive data again after disconnect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a socket has been shut down or closed, you cannot resurect it but have to create a new one.

The general design should be:

```
def show_markers(self):
    scale=0
    active_socket = False

    while True:

        if self.iconAction.isChecked():
            print ('Checked')
            if not active_socket:
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                host = socket.gethostbyname('192.168.225.12')
                s.connect((host, port))
                active_socket = True
            ...
        else:
            if active_socket:
                print('Unchecked going to close socket')
                s.shutdown(10)               # ??
                s.close()
                active_socket = False
```

I have marked the line `shutdown` with an interrogation, because I cannot understand what you are trying to do here. First for portability reasons, you should **never** use numeric values but only the constants provided by the `socket` module. Next `shutdown` is seldom used outside a [graceful shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27777498/3545273) which is not fully implemented here.